# Thread locking a (possible) destoyed mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have 2 thread-safe lists (same type), where each node has a mutex (I know that it's not the optimal solution, but that's what I was asked to do). I have the below function, where I want to match 2 nodes, each one from a different list. The logic is that I pass one node from the first list and I check with all the nodes from the second list.

Here is the type of the node and the list:

```
typedef struct node_type{
    //some data;
    struct node_type *next;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
}node_t;
```

```
typedef struct list_type{
    node_t *head;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
}list_t;
```

Here is the code from the function:

```
node_t *find_match(list_t *l,node_t *n)
{

    node_t *cur,*prev;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&l->lock);
    if(l->head == NULL)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&l->lock);
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cur = l->head;
        while(cur != NULL)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&cur->lock);
            if(n != NULL)
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&n->lock);
                //comparing the data and checks for match.
            }
            else
            {
                //some message or something
                return NULL;
            }
        if(cur == l->head)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&l->lock);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev->lock);
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I'd like to point your attention at the if statement "n != NULL". There, if n is not NULL, then the thread will try to lock the node's mutex. If another thread has it and tries to delete the node, what would happen? Can I avoid it somehow? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: I would first suggest to please sanitize the code example a little:
(1): there is one closing brace missing at the end
(2): please ensure to unlock the list's lock you locked with `pthread_mutex_lock(&l->lock);` at _every exit of the method_. For example before you return "some message or something". 
(3) As the result of `n != NULL` never changes inside the function, it can also be placed at the start of the function before even locking the list.

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: *If another thread has it and tries to delete the node, what would happen?*

**Very short answer**: *What happens is undefined and could be disastrous."*

**Short answer**: *Using the mutex of a node that is deleted in another thread, leads to undefined behaviour. This is also true when that other thread used the mutex during deletion and independent whether it deletes in a locked or unlocked state".*

First off: this is a nice question!

Let's first explain what "deletion" means, so you can judge whether it applies to your situation. Second, it is explained why using the mutex of a deleted node results in undefined and thus incorrect  behaviour (and likely disaster), even if that mutex is used at both deletion and matching in your example implementation of *find_match(l,n)*. Third, some solutions are explored, though you might not like the answers.

## Deletion

*It is assumed that deleting an object also deallocates its memory.* In C, it is expected that this happens via *malloc()* and *free()* or similar.

> The case is explicitly ignored where a custom (de)allocator is used or where all nodes are allocated *before all node processing*, deallocated *after all node processing*, and never reused_. Where "reused" means means that a note is assigned to *node->next* or *list->head* after it is "deleted". In this "static" case, do unlock the node's mutex after deleting though, or all threads in *pthread_mutex_lock(deleted_node)* will patiently wait for a long time...

## Why the undefined behaviour?

Deallocation of memory, for example by calling *free(node)*, must be considered as destroying that memory: values written to it before destroying must be considered lost, while values read from it after destroying should be considered undefined or "random". The C language and runtime simply do not offer any guarantees that information can be conveyed across the destruction of memory, for example because memory is reused or the allocation implementation writes values to it for bookkeeping.

Therefore, any mechanism that depends on conveying information across deallocation of memory suffers from undefined behaviour and certainly is incorrect.

As a result, a mechanism that depends on a mutex *inside* an object that is possibly deleted / deallocated, also suffers from undefined and incorrect behaviour. As the behaviour is undefined, it does not matter if the party that deallocated the node used the mutex, locked or unlocked. The behaviour would simply be *differently undefined*, please check out "Locked-delete and magic values" for more elaboration on this.

## Avoiding the situation

I do not exactly know what you were "asked to do". What is fixed and what are you allowed to change? Depending on that, solutions can range from "none" via "ugly" to "splendid" solutions.

Your current implementation tries to guard against the deletion of node *n* by using *n->mutex*; a part of *n*. As explained above, this leads to undefined behaviour and likely disaster.

To guard guard against deletion of node *n*, you must use something outside of the node that outlives it, let's define it as the *owner*, *owner(n)*. In your example, *owner(n)* is either the list *l_n* if *l_n->head* is *n*, or a node *p* in *l_n* where *p->next* is *p*. Both *l_n* and *p* have a mutex, so locking that mutex before accessing *n* can work. Naturally, the function that deletes *n*, should lock that same mutex.

However, if you are not suppposed to change the function signature of *find_match(l,n)* and are also not supposed to change the data structure of the nodes and the list, there is no way you can know *owner(n)*. After all, *n* has no link to its owner, nor is the owner a function argument.
In this case, the only correct or safe way to solve the problem would be to have a kind of global lock - not part of a node or list - that guards both deleting and *each* matching of *n* with another node. Hm.

If you are allowed to change the signature to *find_match(l,n,o)*, where *o* is the owner, this seems like a solution. However, unless *o* is the list that owns *n* itself, the same ownership problem occurs *recursively*: you cannot trust the mutex of a node *p* that has *p->next* == *n*, unless you lock the mutex of *owner(p)*. Which you do not have. That means you should also have *owner(p)* as a parameter. In other words: it won't solve your problem.

Another way is to use *find_match(l,n,list_that_contains_n)* and always lock on the complete list when either traversing a list, matching an item from a list or deleting/adding an element (lock on both *l* and *list_that_contains_n*, of course). That way you won't need the mutexes from the nodes at all. This speeds up the functions themselves that traverse, delete and add, but reduces concurrent access to them. It depends on the domain and use-case whether that is better or worse.
Locking per element, starting in *list_that_contains_n->head*, can work, but chances are that to do this correctly, you would have to lock all elements in *list_that_contains_n* that precede *n*. The reasons are similar to that of the recursive *owner* argument mentioned earlier. It can be that there is a solution that does not need to lock all these elements, but I guess it is probably not very readable. **If someone can give a readable, correct, proven and efficient example without locking all elements that precede *n*: that would be nice!**

If you *can* change the data structure of nodes and lists, you can add a back-reference to the owner, which is interesting since the owner can be both a list or a node. Better restructure the problem to using a full doubly-linked-list and find a correct implementation for that.

### Conclusion

As you can see, you posed an interesting problem. If you can give a little more information on what you were asked to do, I think somebody - perhaps me - can give you a more precise or suitable  answer!

## Locked-delete and magic values

### But what if I lock the node before deleting it?

Assume that a thread that deletes and deallocates a node, first locks the node's mutex.

If you unlock the node *after* deallocation, *pthread_mutex_unlock(&node->lock)* accesses forfeit memory, likely corrupting other parts of your program. Pray the memory is not reused.

If you do *not* unlock the node, several things can happen. If a thread that executes *find_match(l,node)* happens to be in *pthread_mutex_lock(&node->lock)*, it will wait forever if the memory is not reused. If the memory *is* reused, it is undefined what happens if the thread wakes up, as the mutex is likely overwritten by *something else*. Pray that *pthread_mutex_lock(&node->lock)* just returns an error code...

### But what if I place a magic value in the node lock?

There is no guarantee in the C language that just assigning a value to *node->lock* will ever be seen by another thread. For arguments' sake, let's assume there is such a guarantee on your platform and architecture.

The memory is still potentially reused, so it is still undefined what will happen.

Another question is: what magic value will you put in the node lock? The implementation of a mutex is platform-specific. And POSIX threads only defines a value of an INITIALIZED mutex, not for a mutex that should *not* be used. You could try *pthread_mutex_destroy(node->lock)* but, again, this helps nothing against reused memory.

Comment: Your proportions are very interesting. I will not go into much details. I'll give you the big image. I have to make a stock market simulation for my undergraduate. In there, I must use two lists that one contains buying stocks commands and the other contains selling stocks commands. There are N threads (should work for any number) that read the lists and try to find matches between buying and selling commands. In parallel, although it is not asked directly, our professor told us that deletion of a node must be also possible if, for example, the user that entered the command changed it's mind.

Comment: My thought on it was that "if I have the user tries to delete the node, while it a match search is performing, then I should check if it is deleted, before I try to lock it. But what if I try to lock it and then it gets deleted, because the thread that performs the deletion gets it first? Also, I noticed that checking if it is NULL, is not correct, because it will not be NULL, but it will point to a non-allocated memory address. So again, it will try to read the content of that address and unpredicted things happens.

Comment: I thought of using a boolean variable that indicates when it is in a match, but the deletion can be done, during the matching. For example, let's say that a user added a command and wants to delete it, because he gave wrong quantity on the stocks (how much he wanted to buy/sell). While he performs the deletion command, it is possible for a thread to start searching for a match for that node. It may found a match, it may not. So why should I let this variable stop the deletion, and at the end no match was found?

Comment: As for the double list, I thought about it, but it I found it very difficult to implement it, because I'm not very familiar with making data structures and big projects, especially with a language like C.

Comment: If the ratio deletes over reads is very small, you can also apply the pattern where you lock both  lists completely, however,  using a read-lock for functions that only traverse the list like _find_match(l,n)_ and using a write lock for functions that also delete nodes. As the state of the lists is consistent, you can also simplify _find_match(l,n)  considerably. Pthread offers functions to use read-write locks, though I havent't studied them as C++ offers these a memory model and concurrency tools as part of the language specification ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. The professor said to avoid locking the list, but maybe for this case it's okay. I wanted to avoid locking the lists, for any reason, because of that.

Comment: There is a proper way to individual do this by systematically locking the chain of owners from _owner->head_ towards _n_ in _find_match(l,n,owner)_ and the function that deletes a node. As mentioned: it is tricky, and hard to prove correct (I work in a company and I need my code to be understandable and fixable by others). It might also hurt performance, as you need to lock and release O(N) locks to get safe access to _n_ and then again O(M) locks to find a match in _l_. But maybe your professor can give you more pointers. In C++ it would probably be easier ;-)

Comment: I wish I could do it in C++. I thought of another solution, but I haven't test it yet.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [doc of pthread_mutex_lock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock), it would return EINVAL if "The value specified by mutex does not refer to an initialized mutex object". So presumably you could nullify the `lock` field before freeing the node. Something like this:

```
n->lock = NULL;
free(n); // Or whatever you mean by destroying the node
```

And then when you use mutex_lock you can check its return value (which is a good practice anyway).

Comment: The problem is that it is undefined whether other threads will even see the new value of `n->lock` and perhaps they only see it partially; both leading to mayhem. The only way to make this safe is to ensure that `find_match` and the place where the node is destroyed, are inside the same mutex (apart from other problems).

Comment: There is nothing to prevent malloc() to reuse the same memory location (as the deleted node) and some other thread to write different values to it. This can lead to disastrous results.

Comment: The implementation of a mutex is platform specific, therefore it is dangerous to assume what an uninitialised value is. You can assign PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, bit not something like PTHREAD_MUTEX_UNINITIALIZED. Assigning the former would make pthread_mutex_lock() alter memory locations that could already be in use by something else, leading, again, to disastrous results.

Comment: Because of the three reasons in my previous comments, your answer is a dangerous suggestion, even if it is true you should always check function results. That is the reason that I will down-vote it.

Comment: To comment on my first comment regarding "whether other threads will even see the new value of n->lock", it is true that pthread_mutex_lock() likely ensure the mutex to be _read_  correctly, however, assigning a value a mutex, `n->lock = ....;` does not ensure anything about when that value or parts of it will be possible to be read by other threads.